# Read “x” integer from a string in xml file and replace it using vbscript

Tags: xml, vbscript

I've a xml file with strings and integer, i need to replace the integer inside one of the strings, and i need to do it to multiple files at once.
i already manage to locate the node and replace all the string but not specific integer.

This is my code :

```
    on error resume next

    '***Edit for your needs.
    'Define what the values that you want to inject into the XML file.

     ServerIP = InputBox("Enter Server IP:", _
    "Create File")
     VersionNumber = InputBox("Enter version number:", _
    "Create File")

     'Create XMLDoc object
      Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")

     '****Edit to your needs.
     'Here's where you would want to reference the file path to the configuration file.
     'load up the XML file and place it into xmldoc
      xmlDoc.load "C:\Users\danielc\Desktop\Viewer.xml"

  '***Edit to your needs.
  'Select the node we want to edit
    'The text IS case sensitive
    Set nServerIP = xmlDoc.selectsinglenode ("//Application/Url")
    Set nVersionNumber = xmlDoc.selectsinglenode ("//Application/Version")

'***Edit to your needs.
'Set the text node with the new value
nServerIP.text = ServerIP
nVersionNumber.text = VersionNumber
'nFtpServer.text = sFtpServer

'***Edit to your needs.
'Save the xml document with the new settings.
strResult = xmldoc.save("C:\Users\danielc\Desktop\Viewer.xml")
```

This is the xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Application xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"         xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">`
    <Url>http://192.168.1.63/Shina/ThickClient_x64/Viewer/Viewer.zip</Url>
    <Version>3.0.44.0</Version>
</Application>
```

I need to change the IP address in the  tag.

Anyone ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this section, replace this:

```
'Set the text node with the new value
nServerIP.text = ServerIP
```

With this:

```
'Set the text node with the new value
aURLParts = Split(nServerIP.text,"/")
nServerIP.text = Replace(nServerIP.text,aURLParts(2),ServerIP)
```

Comment: Great, looks like it worked, Do you know how to do it to number of xml files at once ?

Comment: You'd loop through thexmlDoc.load method as many times as required.

Comment: i understand, but how do i do it if every xml is in different location ?